# How can I get to the indoor location without GPS?

Tags: android, location, offsite

I created a reference point in the closed area. How do I get my position depending on this point? For example, 2.5 meters to the right of the reference point.In addition, I want to do this with gyroscopes and accelerometers. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There's two methods.  First is network location.  But this is highly inaccurate (by up to several hundred meters).  The other way is to use beacons.  Bluetooth lowenergy beacons can be precisely placed and you can estimate location based on what beacons are in range and signal strength.  However this method will require 3rd party hardware be installed all over the building in question.

You'll never do it with gyros and accelerometers.  The sensors just aren't accurate enough-  the error in the signal quickly dominates the signal, and there's no way to recalibrate.  With accelerometers, someone else walking across the room causes enough vibrations to cause errors in the accelerometer.

Comment: Project Tango as a option?

Comment: Would require you to hold the phone as a camera, very limiting.  Beacons are going to be at least, possibly more accurate and doesn't require your phone to be out of your pocket.  I'm also not sure how accurate it is in absolute position, vs relative position to walls.  It seems to be more of a depth perspective than anything else.  But depending on use case it could be explored.